# Remove an item from list of taxonomy terms prior to rendering

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

What is the correct way to remove an item from a list within `hook_entity_view` or `hook_preprocess_node`?

I am trying to remove a taxonomy term from a list of terms `EntityReferenceFieldItemList`. I calculate two boolean values, if both are true then the item should be removed from the list.

I've tried removing the second item in the list. That works, but removing the first item results in all the items being removed. Is this because the list keys are no longer sequential?

```
function mymodule_node_view(&$variables) {
  # calculate $field_hide_term and $node_in_past

  foreach($build['field_terms']['#items'] as $key => $term) {
    if ($field_hide_term && $node_in_past) {
      unset($build['field_terms'][$key]); # This also removes other items in the list if key is 0.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `unset()`, you can use `#access = FALSE`, like this:

```
$build['field_terms'][0]['#access'] = FALSE;
```